# Update Nutch to fetch parent of every URL fetched

Tags: java, nutch

As I run Apache Nutch 1.4 crawler, I want to store some additional information. I want to store the parent of every URL.

For example, I want to crawl a page a.html that has 2 anchor links to b.html and c.html So when I crawl a.html, I should get something like this :-

```
a.html null
b.html a.html
c.html a.html
```

I want to store something like this.
I have read how nutch works and have run nutch in eclipse too. I also read fetcher.java and logged where it fetched content. But I got no success in knowing where Nutch fetches the child URLs of a given page. I think this step takes place after parsing step.

Answer (score 2):

I think the information can be obtained by generating linkdb.

**The link database, or linkdb**: This contains the list of known links to each URL, including both the source URL and anchor text of the link. It maintains an inverted link map, listing incoming links for each url.

```
bin/nutch invertlinks crawldb/linkdb -dir crawldb/segments
```

In parsing phase, nutch generates outlinks out of the crawled content and later the newly discovered urls are stored to crawldb in update phase. The new urls are fetch in next cycle / round of nutch crawl.